# How do you change the colour of Mii outfits?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When you unlock the Mech Suit outfit for Mii Brawler it shows a yellow version and a green version. When I try to change the colour it only changes the shirt underneath.

How do you change the colour of anything more than the Mii's shirt?

[image: Mech Suit]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the green mech is for male Miis and the yellow is for female ones. Other than that you can't change it.